# PHP - Using a for loop to count elements in an array instead of using built-in PHP function count

Tags: php, for-loop, count

I'm working on getting a better understand on for loops and how I can use a `for loop` to count elements in an array without the built-in PHP function `count`.

I've been able to do it with the foreach loop, (count the elements in an array) but for some reason the `for loop` isn't working?

**Foreach loop this works:**

```
$month_temp = "78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 81, 76, 73, 68, 72, 73, 75, 65, 74, 63, 67, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73";

$temp = explode(',', $month_temp);

$count = 0;

foreach ($temp as $value) {
    $count++;
}
print_r($count);
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? (I end up with some kind of endless loop without anything being displayed)

**For loop not working:**

```
$month_temp = "78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 81, 76, 73, 68, 72, 73, 75, 65, 74, 63, 67, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73";

$temp = explode(',', $month_temp);

$count = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $temp; $i++) {
    $count++;
}
print_r($count);
```

Comment: $temp is a array not a numerical value. so that your loop is not working

Comment: Why you want to avoid `count` function? You need that as the second parameter for `for` loop.

Comment: I want to see if this can be done without using `count` if it's possible as you can do it with the `foreach loop` per the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People are saying you need to use `count()` to limit your loop. But if you were to use `count()` then whats the purpose? cause your question says you want to see the count without the use of `count()`.

You have to raise the limit considerably long and let the loop go on until there are no more elements in your array then you can break the loop

```
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
     if(isset($temp[$i]))   
        $count++;
     else
         break;
}
print_r($count);
```

Another simplified version

```
$count = 0;
for ($i = 0; TRUE; $i++) {
     if(isset($temp[$i]))  
        $count++;
     else
         break;
}
print_r($count);
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/353154)**

**[Fiddle 2](https://eval.in/353228)**

Comment: That could help. But there is `next`.

Comment: So? they didnt say they dont want to use next. Even so, i have removed `next()`

Comment: i am not sure about OP's requirement. Why not built in functions? :o

Comment: @Hanky 웃 Panky I was able to get it to work based on your suggestion with the `isset()`  and letting the loop run out but I didn't need to do `$i < 1000000`, I just used what I had originally with `$< $temp` and it worked fine. Can you update your answer to reflect this?

Comment: But i think that is waste of looping to loop through 1000000 times if our array just have 8-10 items then what.

Comment: @No sunil that is incorrect. As soon as the array elements are done loop breaks out. It doesn't go upto 10000000.

Comment: @walter You do have to use a number which you think will be more than your array's length.  Using `$i<$temp` might also make it work for you but that is wrong. You cant compare a number with an array and the comparison results in `FALSE` that's why the loop keeps going.

Comment: @walter i just made an edit for you to make it simpler.

Comment: @ Hanky 웃 Panky I've never seen true; being used in the counter parameter, can you explain this some more for my own edification?

Comment: Yep that simply means  there is no limit. Because it will always be TRUE it will never stop until our break stops it within the loop. This can also be understood by a simple example. When you say `$i<5` you mean to say while `$i<5 == TRUE` So if you say while TRUE that means an endless loop. But then our `break` stops it when needed.

Comment: I see. Well thanks for explaining and providing viable solution for my learning purposes. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're using the exploded string (the array) inside your `for`:

```
$temp = explode(',', $month_temp);
^
|------------------v
for ($i = 0; $i < $temp; $i++) {
// doesn't make sense
```

Sidenote: Just use the `count()` function if your intent is to get the number of elements inside the exploded array. That loop is actually superfluous.

Note: You can device a way using `for` without using a count thru array pointers:

```
$month_temp = "78, 60, 62, 68, 71, 68, 73, 85, 66, 64, 76, 63, 81, 76, 73, 68, 72, 73, 75, 65, 74, 63, 67, 65, 64, 68, 73, 75, 79, 73";
$temp = explode(',', $month_temp);
for (current($temp); ($i = current($temp)) !== false; ($i = next($temp))) {
    // do something
    echo trim($i) , '<br/>';

}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OZZkZU)

Comment: Even without using explode, say I just use the month_temp as an array I still get some endless loop. Of course I can use `count`, but that's defeats the purpose. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @walter yes you really need the count to have a condition, but there is another way though, thru array pointers, check out my demo

Answer (score -1):

`$i < $temp` is not the condition you want. I'm not certain how PHP is doing the comparison, but you're comparing an integer to an array. That's always evaluating as true, so the loop continues for eternity.

Ironically, you want `$i < count($temp)`! That will let the loop run until $i is the same as the number of elements in the array, at which point you'll have three expressions ($i, $count and count($temp)) representing the number of elements in the array.

So this is perhaps not the best way to test your for loop skills. Perhaps try running through a collection of integers to find the index of a particular number, to find the sum of all the numbers, the largest number, the smallest number, the range, the average, etc etc :)

Answer (score -1):

you can use sizeOf function in place of count like

```
$max = sizeof($huge_array);
for($i = 0; $i < $max;$i++)
{
code...
}
```

If you do not want to use count or sizeof then it better you use

```
foreach($arr as $ar){
//Code here
}
```

Except this i do not thing there is any method available.

Comment: Can this be done without using any built-in PHP function including `sizeof`?